# How do I skip a file line if data already exists in the previous line?

Tags: python, for-loop

Heres function(open_file()) that receives an opened csv file. For every line, I made a for loop to go through every line. For every state, create a key dictionary for state name, while making it's city and date as a value in list. However, if the city AND date are the same, skip that line.

Heres the csv file:

```
 State      City      Date
Michigan    Detroit   3/31/00
Michigan    Detroit   3/31/00
Michigan    Detroit   3/31/00
Michigan    Detroit   4/1/00
Michigan    Detroit   4/2/00
```

Heres my code so far:

```
def read_file(fp):

reader = csv.reader(fp)
state = {}
for line in reader:
    city = ''
    date = ''
    if line[1] != city:
        city = line[1]
        if line[2] != date:
            date = line[2]
print(state)
```

the correct output:

```
  state = {'Michigan': [['Detroit', '3/31/2000'], 
          ['Detroit', '4/1/2000'],['Detroit', '4/2/2000']]
```

Comment: instead of a list of lists, make the values in your dictionary a set of tuples. Identical tuple entries will be merged.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but the output has to be as it is, can't be in tuple, has to be in lists in order to function in the other functions. thanks!

Comment: you can always convert back to a list of lists after reading in from file...

Comment: but my main question, how would I skip the line if the date and city are the same as the previous ones?

Comment: you could test `if (line[1], line[2]) in state[line[0]]:` before updating, but I'd be willing to bet it's faster just to `.update` the set and let hashing throw out duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ingest your input the other way: make the dict key `city + '|' + date`.  This will automatically eliminate any duplicates.  You don't skip the line; you just let it overwrite the (identical) existing dict entry.
2. Reverse the dictionary (switch value and key)
3. When you perform this reversal, `split` the new value at the vertical bar.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not a limiting issue, create one set to keep track of occurred elements. This would not prevent you from keeping the order of the elements because you don't change the way you add to the lists.
When `if element in set:` simply `continue`.